# All class names have turned red in Android Studio, but code still runs and compiles

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I experienced a power surge and after I restarted my Android Studio, all my class names have turned red, but my code compiles and runs perfectly. But I can't have access to certain class functionalities. I have rebuilt and also cleaned the project but to no avail. I've also reinstalled Android Studio.

[image: SnapShot of sample activity]

Comment: I think it a linker problem, You just should restart your application.

Comment: I've done that a couple of times today, but no effect has been seen

Comment: Does File | Invalidate Caches help?

Comment: This happened to me because of these reasons:

* There was something wrong with the library that I added through gradle
* My layout file(s) have errors that was not resolved
* Compiling and updating gradle failed

Comment: Clicking on File | Invalidate worked. Thanks and God bless you @CrazyCoder

Comment: Invalidate didnt worked , updating com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.+ from com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0 changed AppCompatActivity red symbol rest not working